# Countdown Timer to display on a site

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am a content editor for a number of websites and recently I had to work on some of the technical parts of the site as well.

The servers hosting our sites are reset daily at 4pm Singapore Time (GMT +8). I am looking to create a Javascript that will display a countdown to the user around 3.45pm SG time. This would be a countdown timer that would count down to 4pm, and there will be a message to say that the site will be going down. After 4.15pm, the countdown as well as the message would then be removed.

Our sites are created using a basic framework created by AtHomeNet.com; the pages are ASP pages. I have no control over the server itself (all are controlled by AHN.com), nor am I able to access the server. I say this because I have read through some of the topics in StackOverflow and I understand that it is much better to check against the server time rather than to check against system time. Unfortunately, as I recall, Javascript is client-side, and I would not (for reasons stated above) be able to have anything included for the server-side.

I have looked online for some scripts; however, I am not sure how I should only display and hide the message at certain times (i.e. only display at 3.45pm, and hide after 4.15pm)

Any and all feedback and help is greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
var d = new Date();
var m = d.getMinutes();
var h = d.getHours();

var hShowMsgStart = 15;
var mShowMsgStart = 45;

var hShowMsgEnd = 16;
var mShowMsgEnd = 15;

labelRef.innerText = "The time is now: " + h.toString() + m.toString() + "hrs";

if ((h >= hShowMsgStart && m >= mShowMsgStart) || (h <= hShowMsgEnd && m<=mShowMsgEnd) {
   //alert the user that it is 1545hrs
    labelRef.innerText = "The time is now: " + h.toString() + m.toString() + "hrs. Please note that the site will be temporarily down for 5 minutes from 4pm till 4.15pm SG time. Please save your work and log out before 4pm SG time";
}
```

Comment: Just so I'm clear - you have no way of editing the ASP on the server-side? Not even to upload a script that could at least send timing information?

Comment: @AnonJr, unfortunately, no. There's no way for us to edit the ASP over at the server side. We can request AHN tech support to upload a JS script, but that's pretty much about it.

Comment: That makes things ... interesting. @Marius probably has the closest thing you can get within the constraints you are working in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remeber that Javascript uses the internal clock of the client computer so you have no control over which timezone the user is in unless you use some third party library (but thats not what this question is about).

To achieve what you're trying to you should use setInterval.

> The setInterval() method will wait a specified number of milliseconds, and then execute a specified function, and it will continue to execute the function, once at every given time-interval. - from w3schools.

Something along this way:

```
    function checkTime() {
       var id = "warningLabel"; // the id of the label you want to use.
       var d = new Date();
       var m = d.getMinutes();
       var h = d.getHours();

       var hShowMsgStart = 15;
       var mShowMsgStart = 45;

       var hShowMsgEnd = 16;
       var mShowMsgEnd = 15;
       var label = document.getElementById(id);
       if ((h >= hShowMsgStart && m >= mShowMsgStart) || (h <= hShowMsgEnd && m <= mShowMsgEnd)) {
           label.style.display = "block";
       } else {
           label.style.display = "none";
       }
       label .innerText = "The time is now: " + h.toString() + m.toString() + "hrs. Please note that the site will be temporarily down for 5 minutes from 4pm till 4.15pm SG time. Please save your work and log out before 4pm SG time";
   }

   setInterval(checkTime, 1000);  // now it will run the checkTime function every second.
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the help. I have submitted this code to the Tech Support team at AHN for them to upload to my site. If this works, I'll set this as the answer!